# How to make my Route work with a controller?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', 'StudentsController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('register', 'StudentsController@create')->name('create');
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class StudentsController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    return view('layout/main');
  }
    public function create()
    {
      return view('register');
    }
}
```

Hello,
I've been having issues with routing, each time I go to /register I get a 404 and I can't find the problem in the code.
The default route works and I tried moving the route to the top.
The route exists in **php artisan route:list**.
When I try to return view('register') without the controller it seems to work but I need it to work with it.
**Edit
I am trying to load my register.blade.php file which is located in the views folder and seems to work fine when I am not using the controller, the routing is in the web.php file.

Clearing the cache doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Is StudentsController in Controllers dir?

Comment: please add where and how you are trying to use the route in your question.

Comment: The StudentsController is in the Controllers dir, and it works with '/' directory.

Comment: I am using the route in the web.php file in the laravel framework, I am simply trying to load my register.blade.php file using the controller when someone goes to '/register' directory.

Comment: Try `php artisan cache:clear` then `composer du`

Comment: I tried, It still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'd like to suggest a better way for these kinds of problems by installing Xdebug and trying to trace the application line by line from bootstrap to find out the problem much easier.

Comment: sounds like rewrite isn't enabled on the web server

Comment: Thank you vivek_23!
It worked after I added index.php/register .
lagbox the rewrite option was enabled but playing with it didn't seem to remove the index.php requirement .

Comment: How can I fix this?
 Everything seems OK and the routing works fine with a different project.